# multiple conditions in while loop

Tags: bash

I have got 2 bash snippets that work perfectly:

```
MODE=a;while [[ !("${MODE}" =~ ^[0-9]+$) ]];do read -p 'mode?' MODE;done
```

and

```
MODE=a;while [[ "${MODE}" != 'b' ]]; do read -p 'mode?' MODE;done
```

I want to merge these 2 conditions. I tried to follow the recommandations from this post ([multiple conditions in while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534595/bash-scripting-multiple-conditions-in-while-loop)). but it does not work for me:

**#single POSIX test command with -o operator:**

```
MODE=a;while [ !("${MODE}" =~ ^[0-9]+$) -o "${MODE}" != 'b' ];do read -p 'mode?' MODE;done
```

**#2 POSIX test commands joined in a list with ||:**

```
MODE=a;while [ !("${MODE}" =~ ^[0-9]+$) ] || [ "${MODE}" != 'b' ]; do read -p 'mode?' MODE;done
```

**#2 BASH conditional expressions with || operator:**

```
MODE=a;while [[ !("${MODE}" =~ ^[0-9]+$) ]] || [[ "${MODE}" != 'b' ]]; do read -p 'mode?' MODE;done
```

**#2 BASH arthmetic expression joined in a list with ||:**

```
MODE=a;while (( !("${MODE}" =~ ^[0-9]+$) )) || (( "${MODE}" != 'b' )); do read -p 'mode?' MODE;done
```

**#a single BASH arithmetic expresion with the || operator:**

```
MODE=a;while (( !("${MODE}" =~ ^[0-9]+$) || "${MODE}" != 'b' )); do read -p 'mode?' MODE;done
```

thanx folks!!

Comment: You need to combine the tests with an AND operator, not OR. See ["Why does non-equality check of one variable against many values always return true?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-does-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-return-tr), ["Bash multiple ors don't work with negatives"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59858793/bash-multiple-ors-dont-work-with-negatives), and [Wikipedia on De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: What does "it does not work for me" mean, exactly? If you test those, you should get some rather obvious errors. E.g. you correctly have `[[ .. ]]` in the first examples, so why not keep with that all the way? Is the `=~` even a valid operator in `[ .. ]` or in an arithmetic context?

Comment: @Ikkachu: read the linked post plz.

Comment: @achille, nothing in there uses `=~` within `[ .. ]` or `(( .. ))`.

Comment: "_I want to merge these 2 conditions_" in what way do you want to merge them? So that it either is true/false, or both must be true/false, or...? It's not clear to me from your examples what it is you want to achieve, only that what you've tried doesn't work

Comment: @roaima: how can you understand the latter without understanding the former :-)?

Answer (score 0):

thank you Gordon !

```
MODE=a;while [[ !("${MODE}" =~ ^[0-9]+$) ]] && [[ "${MODE}" != 'b' ]]; do read -p 'mode?' MODE;done
```